# New to Ubuntu Desktop for windows

Tags: cd-command

I have done several searches to determine how to change to my C drive in windows when using Ubuntu Desktop for Windows.

Can someone point me to a manual or tutorial where I can learn how to navigate the Windows file system from Ubuntu?

Regards,

Phlip

Comment: You should be able to navigate in the Windows file system without problems. It is not called C but it start with /dev/sd.

Comment: Hi Phlip, the Linux world is a little different. We do not have a "C" drive - physical drives in linux are "mounted". That is your drive will be attached to a folder (might be /mnt/ or sth). But: Ubuntu should show that drive on your desktop. Be aware that you should not hibernate your windows. You have to shut it down completely. 
So: can you see a "disk" icon on your linux desktop? Then either double click on it or right mouse click it and select "mount"

Comment: @Phlip on the Windows side you can use `powercfg -h off` to turn hibernation off, this _should_ also get rid of that hybrid "shutdown" Windows 10 got. Additionally you can simply name your drives by giving them a meaningful label on the Windows side (right-click on the drive and edit the properties). After that `blkid` and `lsblk` (`lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT|grep -v ^loop`) should give you a clue as to where your particular drive is mounted. If you only got one drive, it's even easier.

Answer (score 0):

I used the command "`cd /mnt/c`" and that did the trick.